# How to get Substr of values

Tags: python, django, substr

Hi I have the following query in my views.py

```
m = Request.objects.filter(Q(type__icontains='4'), Q(wt__in =['giga','mega']))
context['all_items'] = m.values('type1').order_by('type1')
```

Its giving values `sasoo, masoo, pisoo, kusoo etc.`

How can I implement the Django [`Substr`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/database-functions/#substr) in this case so that my html will display values as `sa, ma, pi, ku, ..`

Comment: Without Substr, this will give you the same result: `context['all_items']=[{'type1':x[0]['type1'][0:1]} for x in m.values('type1').order_by('type1')]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `annotate` the model

```
from django.db.models.functions import Substr
m = Request.objects.filter(Q(type__icontains='4'), Q(wt__in =['giga','mega']))
context['all_items'] = m.annotate(mysubstring=Substr('type1',1,2)).order_by('type1')
```

In template:

```
{% for obj in all_items %}
    {# Use obj.mysubstring #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Sayse: Tried that. But am getting this error `No module named functions`. Any idea?

Comment: @vellattukudy - What version of django are you using?

Comment: @Sayse: does it matter if order_by is before or after the annotate? It seems that it does, with fewer letters the sort may be different

Comment: Django version 1.6.5

Comment: @vellattukudy - Substr was added in [1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.8/#query-expressions-conditional-expressions-and-database-functions), you can't use it in 1.6.5, slice is probably your only option

Comment: @AviahLaor - The sort isn't applied to the substring so it doesn't matter at all

Answer (score 1):

You can use [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter in your template:

```
{% for item in all_items %}
  {{ item.type1|slice:":2" }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner

```
context['all_items'] = [i[:2] for i in context['all_items']]
```

Comment: If this is building upon the op's original code then it won't work since you can't slice dictionary objects